# construct url dynamically (name view as argument) with name space url tag in Django template

Tags: django, url

In a Django template, I want to construct dynamically urls

I try to concatenate (see below) but got an error :

```
Could not parse the remainder: '+key+'_index'' from ''ecrf:'+key+'_index''
```

```
{% for key, values in forms.items %}
   <!-- for exemple a key would be 'inclusion' -->
   <a href="{% url 'ecrf:'+key+'_create' %}">{{ key|capfirst }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

urls

```
app_name='ecrf'
urlpatterns = [
    path('inclusion/create/', views.InclusionCreate.as_view(), name='inclusion_create'),
```

expected result:

```
<a href="/localhost/ecrf/inclusion">Inclusion</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`add` template tag[Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#add) to add strings together:

```
{% for key, values in forms.items %}
   <!-- for example a key would be 'inclusion' -->
   <a href="{% url 'ecrf:'|add:key|add:'_create' %}">{{ key|capfirst }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

But this feels a bit hacky to me, perhaps your `forms` dictionary can be restructured so that such logic is done in the view itself? For example the dictionary can be:

```
{'inclusion': {'value': <some_value>, 'create_url': 'ecrf:inclusion_create'}}
```

And in your template your loop would be:

```
{% for key, values in forms.items %}
   <!-- for example a key would be 'inclusion' -->
   <a href="{% url values.create_url %}">{{ key|capfirst }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```